# Creating EC2 Instances from an AMI with different hostname for Splunk

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, splunk

I am trialling using Splunk to log messages from IIS across our deployment. I notice that when I spin up a new EC2 instance from a custom AMI/Image it has the same PC 'hostname' as the parent image it was created from.

If I have a splunk forwarder setup on this new server it will forward data under the same hostname as the original image, making a distinction for reporting impossible.

Does anyone know of anyway that I can either dynamically set the hostname when creating an EC2 instance OR configure it in splunk as such that I specify a hostname for new forwarders?

Many Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building the AMI, just bake in a simple startup script that sets the machine hostname dynamically.

If using a prebuilt AMI, connect to the machine once it's alive and set the host name (same script).

OR

Via Splunk: hostname is configured in. Just need to update these or run the splunk setup after you've set the hostname.
$SPLUNKHOME/etc/system/local/inputs.conf
$SPLUNKHOME/etc/system/local/server.conf

script idea above also applies to this (guessing you are baking the AMI with spunk already in there).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I'm building an ami with splunk baked in, I think you're right, I'll just use a startup script to set the host name and then re-run the splunk setup to push this to the conf files. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Splunk has various "stale" configuration that should not be shared across multiple instances of Splunk Enterprise, or the Universal Forwarder.

You can cleanup this stale data using built in Splunk commands.

```
./splunk clone-prep-clear-config
```

See:  http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.1.3/Admin/Integrateauniversalforwarderontoasystemimage